# custom comparator for pointers in a deque

Tags: c++

I have a deque of pointers to a struct.
I am trying to sort the deque with a comparator like the following:

```
struct timeCompE {
// ascending order by tt(unsigned long long), c(string), id(string)
bool operator() (const LogItem* a, const LogItem* b)const {
    if (a->tt == b->tt) {
        if (a->c == b->c) {
            return (a->id < b->id);
        } else {
            return (a->c < b->c);
        }
    } else {
        return (a->tt < b->tt);
    }
}};
```

however, the sort function doesn't seem to work the way I want it to:

```
std::sort(myDeque.begin(), myDeque.end(), timeCompE());
```

The code compiles, but the sort function doesn't work the way I want it to...
I've tried looking for cases like this but couldn't find the exact.
Also, am I able to pass in the const LogItem* by reference instead of value like i'm doing above? if so, what is the syntax for it? (I couldn't get that version to compile)

thank you in advance.

Comment: _"but the sort function doesn't work the way I want it to"_ Well, could you please elaborate what's actually the way you want it to work?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought people would understand by reading the comment line in the code `ascending order by tt, c, id` tt is an unsigned long long and c and id are both strings

Comment: What are the types of `tt`, `c`, and `id` ?

Comment: You code looks ok (even though we can't see the LogItem definition), except you should change the * to & when specifying the args.  That will make them references which is what the sort function is expecting.

Comment: but theyre not LogItem objects, theyre pointers to LogItems

Comment: Since you are trying to sort your deque, it looks like you are looking for a different container - the one capable of sorting your data automatically as it gets queued. Take a look at [`std::priority_queue<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: @hrk_er ok, I missed the part where you said it was a deque of pointers.  Can you then elaborate on what is not working.  Give an example.  The code you posted looks correct but of course it's not the whole picture.

Comment: when I run the sort function as stated above, it segfaults immediately. so I'm guessing when the comparator runs it doesn't know where or how to access the member variables?

Comment: Can you please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? As others have commented, nothing's obviously wrong with your code. Do you have `nullptr`s in your `deque`? It looks like the body of your comparator can be simplified to `return std::tie(a->tt, a->c, a->id) < std::tie(b->tt, b->c, b->id);`

Comment: If you post a mcve, we can try to compile and run it.  If not, there is nothing more we can do. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the syntax/interface of your comparator provided that `myDeque` actually stores pointers to `LogItem` (`deque<LogItem*>` or `deque<const LogItem*>`).

Even the logic inside your comparator appears correct (slightly verbose but it should sort your elements in ascending order as desired).

If you're immediately segfaulting on executing the code, probably the problem is not with your comparator or even the sort but with respect to what you are storing inside the deque (ex: dangling pointers, nulls, pointers to data that was invalidated, etc).

Since it was requested, the signature for the comparator predicate if you want to compare references rather pointers would be:

```
bool operator() (const LogItem& a, const LogItem& b) const
```

However, that would only apply if you were storing LogItem objects and not pointers to them in the deque (`deque<LogItem>`, e.g., not `deque<LogItem*>`).